# Make a portable HTPC with Tv tuner

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w

How can I make a portable HTPC with usb Tv tuner? I've got a Raspberry pi Zero W with usb hub, and an USB Tv tuner. I want to use this in a truck, I mean I want to watch movies with kodi, and watch DVB-T2 Tv channels. And I only got the raspberry (no laptop)

Comment: You could have a look at TVHeadend. (Google it.)

Comment: I think a Pi Zero will struggle, I would suggest a Pi3B+.

Comment: I googled and it says if I read it good, the tv headend need a server, and I only got Pi in the truck, how can I use it?

Comment: Server and client can be the same computer. Main question is if the Zero is powerful enough to do both